# Compatibility conditions for parabolic regularity

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the compatibility conditions for regularity of second order parabolic equations.
Let's consider the equation $u_t - Lu = f$ with $u(0)=g$ on $\Omega \times [0,T)$ with $u = 0$ on $\Gamma_T$, the parabolic boundary of $\Omega \times [0,T)$.

We need the assumptions that
$\frac{d^{m-1}f}{d^{m-1}}(0) - Lg_{m-1} \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ for the $L^2$ theory to work to conclude smoothness up to the boundary (I'm presuming $f$ and $\Omega$ are smooth). As far as I can tell this is required so that we don't have the following situation:

$u_t - u_{xx} = 0$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with $u(0,x)=1$ and $u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0$. Here we clearly can't have differentiability up to the boundary since $1 \neq 0$. However after time $t = 0$ it would appear to me that this problem goes away, ie. that the solutions are smooth up to the boundary *except* at $t=0$. Is this the case? Can people perhaps share insightful examples?

Comment: I don't know what $f$, $g_{m-1}$, and $L$ are in the second sentence. Also, you appear to have a typo in the formula that starts the second paragraph.

Comment: I also continue to be baffled why you aren't consulting your classmates and teachers at Courant before posting on MathOverflow. Aren't you able to get helpful answers from them?

Comment: More often than not I don't get helpful answers. I perhaps would if I bothered professors more but I like to do that in extreme moderation. At least here if people don't care to answer they don't need to. If they have something helpful to say they can offer it. 

Comment: I should also add that I have my qualification exams next week and so this is why I am constantly asking questions. I have a million questions which come up and I do indeed ask people here. However some of them I appreciate multiple perspectives which this website offers.

Comment: Do you know any classmates who are also taking the exam? It's *very* helpful to struggle through these things together with someone else in the same situation. Your questions are a bit too out of context to be able to offer clear help. Are you trying to solve a problem from an old exam, or are you asking about something you're reading in a book? If the latter, from where? And when's the exam?

Comment: The exam is next tuesday. This isn't a problem for a textbook or old exam or anything. I am responsible for 'knowing' parabolic reguliarty on my exam and I'm using Evans as my main source. He seems to only discuss full regularity up to the boundary and doesn't seem to make any points about what is going on in the interior and near the boundary away from $t=0$ (he makes one small remark about interior regularity). These are just questions I thought of when thinking of really basic questions I might get like heat equation on $[0,1]$ with $u(0,x)=x(1-x)$. Do I have $C^{\infty}$ solutions? etc..

Comment: And I find in these types of situations that ultimately someone with more experience is needed (even though the question appears elementary). I have indeed discussed this with some other students but we didn't make a concrete conclusion.

Comment: What about more advanced students who have already passed the exam? You have been asking very good, interesting, but often difficult questions that many of us already with phds and published papers can't answer. You should really try to get a better sense of what is expected of you so you don't expend too much effort things that you don't need to know. Also, could you clarify the question above?

Comment: Not that it's a big deal, but "regularity" is misspelt in the title of your question.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: I fixed the typo in the title of the question. Unfortunately there is still the issue of the first sentence of the second paragraph....